# How can I use an accessor to create a text field from a binary field?

Tags: php, laravel, accessor

In Laravel 5, I have a binary field called 'microchip,' which is a binary field. I would like to build an accessor function which outputs "yes," or "no," if the original field contains a 1 or 0 respectively. I have this:

```
    public function getMicrochipTextAttribute($input)
    {
    switch($input)
    {
        case 0:
            return "No";
        break;
        case 1:
            return "Yes";
        break;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I use $model->microchip_text, it is returning "No," regardless of the contents of the $input. Regardless of whether $input contains a 1 or 0, it is outputting "No."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is because Eloquent doesn't know what `$input` you are using, because you are creating a accessor for a new property and not for an existing one. Instead, try this:

```
public function getMicrochipTextAttribute()
{
    switch($this->attributes['microchip'])
    {
        case 0:
            return "No";
        break;
        case 1:
            return "Yes";
        break;
    }
}
```

or a shorter version:

```
public function getMicrochipTextAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['microchip'] ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. So, would I be right by assuming that using $input as a parameter is a practice reserved for mutators and not accessors, then?

Comment: @KinsDotNet `$input` works for accessors, but only when you are making an accessor for an existing property. e.g.: `getMicrochipAttribute` (`microchip` exists? yes, so inject its value).  `getFooBarAttribute` (`foo_bar` exists? no, so inject nothing).